# Field in singleton unexpectedly null - Why?

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, singleton

I have the following singleton in a JavaFX program, which is intended to make it easier to switch between different screens of the application:

```
public class ScreenManager() {

    private Stage mainStage;

    private static ScreenManager instance;

    private ScreenManager() {
        // TODO
    }

    public static ScreenManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null ) {
            return new ScreenManager();
        } else {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public void initialize(Stage mainStage) {
        this.mainStage = mainStage;
    }

    public void switchToScreen(String fxmlPath) {
        Parent newScreenRoot;

        try {
            URL pathToFxml = getClass().getResource(fxmlPath);
            newScreenRoot = fxmlLoader.load(pathToFxml);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to load FXML", e);
        }

            Scene newScreen = new Scene(newScreenRoot);
            mainStage.setScene(newScreen);
            mainStage.setMaximized(true);
        }

}
```

Initialize is called with a reference to the main stage during JavaFX's `start()` method.

However, when I later call `getInstance()` and then try to switch screens, I fail with a `NullPointerException` because `mainStage` is null. It seems that the field is becoming null in between it's first use and it's subsequent use. How?

Why would this be happening?

Comment: You never initialize `instance`...

Comment: Oh my god. I've been doing this whole programming thing for 6 years now and somehow missed that. I ran through it in the debugger and everything. This is what happens when you sleep 4 hours a night.

Comment: Many programmers recommend against using a singleton at all these days; you might consider a dependency-injection solution instead.

Comment: I considered it, but I'm working with a *very* green (student) team right now and if I tried to introduce them to DI and IoC, they'd probably melt.

Comment: FWIW a grad student I'm working with asked me recently how long I had been programming. I had to calculate it... I was pretty shocked to find it's been 38 years. So you are still kind of a newb in my book, if it makes you feel better :).

Comment: @James_D Actually, I'm still getting the error. I have ensured that instance is initialized.

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE]?

Comment: Nevermind, a Gradle clean and rebuild solved it. Apparently gradle was borking that one up.

Answer (score 3):

You never initialize `instance`, so your `getInstance()` method returns a new object every time (it's almost the opposite of a singleton; you've made it really hard to use the same instance more than once...).

You need

```
public static ScreenManager getInstance() {
    if (instance == null ) {
        instance = new ScreenManager();
    } 
    return instance;
}
```

Just a couple of comments: many programmers discourage the use of the singleton pattern, as it has a number of issues with it. You might consider using dependency injection instead. Also, since the primary purpose of this singleton seems to be to give access to a stage, note that you can get a reference to the stage any node is contained in via `Node.getScene().getWindow()` (you may need to downcast the result if you need `Stage`-specific functionality). Since controllers can always be given access to some node in the UI hierarchy, you may not need this at all.

Finally, if you do decide you need/want to use a singleton, another way of implementing a singleton pattern is to use an enum with just one value:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public enum ScreenManager {

    INSTANCE ;

    private Stage mainStage;


    public void initialize(Stage mainStage) {
        this.mainStage = mainStage;
    }

    public void switchToScreen(String fxmlPath) {
        Parent newScreenRoot;

        try {
            URL pathToFxml = getClass().getResource(fxmlPath);
            newScreenRoot = FXMLLoader.load(pathToFxml);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to load FXML", e);
        }

            Scene newScreen = new Scene(newScreenRoot);
            mainStage.setScene(newScreen);
            mainStage.setMaximized(true);
        }

}
```

And then you can do things like

```
ScreenManager.INSTANCE.initialize(primaryStage);
ScreenManager.INSTANCE.switchToScreen(...);
```

etc.

There are, in general, some advantages to this approach over implementing it directly: for one, this is immediately thread-safe, which is not true of the solution I posted at the top of this post.

Comment: Sigh... Sometimes I wonder if this engineering degree is doing me any good , lol